# Getting duplicate couples values error in pdata.frame even when there is no duplicate values

Tags: r, gis

So I've tried running the following code from a panel dataset of weekly hospital observations and I'm getting a recurrent error, which I believe is driven by `plm`:

```
finalprepostdataset2<-finalprepostdataset%>%
  filter(state=="AL"|state=="GA"| state=="NC"| state=="SC"|state=="MI"|state=="FL")%>%
  group_by(year, week) %>%
  mutate(group = cur_group_id())%>%
  ungroup()

finalprepostdataset2<-unique(finalprepostdataset2, by=c("hospital_pk", "group"))
  
finalprepostdataset_sp<-st_as_sf(x=finalprepostdataset2, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")

finalprepostdataset_sp <- as(finalprepostdataset_sp, "Spatial")

formula<-y~i(ranking, ref=0)+x+z

result.F.AIC<-GWPR(formula=formula, bw=211.73, data=finalprepostdataset2, SDF=finalprepostdataset_sp, 
index=c("hospital_pk", "group"),  
adaptive = T, p = 2, 
effect = "time", model = "within", kernel = "gaussian", longlat = FALSE)

Warning message:
In pdata.frame(data, index) :
  duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
 to find out which, use, e.g., table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
```

I've read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57638386/troubleshooting-duplicate-couples-id-time-in-resulting-pdata-frame) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677576/panel-data-models-duplicate-couples-error-when-there-are-no-duplicate-couples) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85909/why-does-a-fixed-effect-ols-need-unique-time-elements/390667#390667), and maybe I'm a bit confused because hospital-and-week-level data is the lowest level of fixed effects available. There are no duplicate values:

```
finalprepostdataset2<-finalprepostdataset%>%
filter(state=="AL"|state=="GA"| state=="NC"| state=="SC"|state=="MI"|state=="FL")%>%
group_by(year, week) %>%
mutate(group = cur_group_id())%>%
ungroup()%>%
get_dupes(hospital_pk, group)

No duplicate combinations found of: hospital_pk, group
```

So I could use some help understanding why I'm still getting errors.